# Simple Negative Lookahead

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I get this:

```
import re; 
print re.findall(r"q(?=u)", "qqq queen quick qeel")
> ['q', 'q'] # for queen and quick
```

But I don't get this:

```
import re; 
print re.findall(r"q(?!=u)", "qqq queen quick qeel")
> ['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q'] # every q matches
```

I expected only 4 qs to match because the negative lookahead should see that in the word **qeel** for example, the letter after the q is **not** u.

What gives?

Comment: You don't need semicolon after import

Comment: Also, docs say negative lookahead is `(?!...)` This is just a typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is

```
import re 
print(re.findall(r"q(?!u)", "qqq queen quick qeel"))
#                  ---^---
# ['q', 'q', 'q', 'q']
```

---

Without the `=`, that is. Otherwise, you don't want to have `=u` in front which is true for **all** of your `q`s here. In general, a positive lookahead is formed via `(?=...)` whereas a negative one is just `(?!...)`.

---

*Sidenote*: the `;` is not needed at the end of the line unless you want to write everything in one line which is not considered "Pythonic" but totally valid:

```
import re; print(re.findall(r"q(?!u)", "qqq queen quick qeel"))
```

Comment: ugh, i'm going to go pull all my hair out now. and thanks!

Comment: @NickLang: No worries, glad to help.